# Why does RVM point to the wrong rubygems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I switched to RVM a few months ago, and don't recall installing any new gems until yesterday. When I require the new gem, I get:

```
/home/rob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': no such file to load -- mspire/peak_list (LoadError)
```

Even though:

```
gem install mspire
```

worked just fine.

I am guessing that the issue lies in the fact that Ruby is looking for the gem in 1.9.1's rubygems instead of 1.9.2 (the version I am using). I set the version with `rvm use`. Is there something I am omitting?

Comment: Do you have system ruby installed as well as ruby within rvm?

Comment: Did you set it with `rvm use 1.9.2 --default`?

Comment: how do you require it ? is it in Gemfile ?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby >= 1.9.1 always saves its libraries in a 1.9.1. directory. This denotes that all those Ruby versions adhere to 1.9.1 compatibility. It does not denote the actual Ruby version used.

Your gems should be saved in `/home/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems`. There should be a directory named after the gem and the exact version in there. The paths set by RVM can be checked with `rvm info`. The `GEM_PATH` should look like `/home/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290:/home/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global`.

Make sure you install the gem with the exact same Ruby and gemset you are using it with. If you change the Ruby or the gemset, you have to re-install the gem.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. My rvm info does have the correct GEM_PATH. I still get the error when I re-run gem install mspire.

Comment: Hmmm, might it be a permission issue? Please run `chown "$(id -u):$(id -g)"; chmod a+rX /home/rob/.rvm` to make sure you can properly access all the required files.